# TypeScript: implements does not work when passing instance to function

Tags: typescript, typeguards

I have a `TypeScript` `interface` that define an event emitter

```
export interface Emitter<A extends {}> {
  on: <E extends keyof A>(event: E, listener: A[E]) => any;
  off: <E extends keyof A>(event: E, listener: A[E]) => any;
}
```

This basically means that if I put a type in `Emitter<A>` like so:

```
interface Api {
  discover: (peripheral: Peripheral) => void;
  service: (service: Service) => void;
}
```

This

```
Emitter<Api>
```

makes sure that I can only use the combination of `"discover"` + `(peripheral: Peripheral) => void` and `"service"` + `(service: Service) => void` for the `on` and `off` functions. Like so:

```
const myImplementation: Emitter<Api> = {/* ... */}; // dummy code

myImplementation.on("discover", (peripheral: Peripheral) => {}); // works
myImplementation.on("service", (service: Service) => {}); // works

myImplementation.on("asdasd", (peripheral: Peripheral) => {}); // nope
myImplementation.on("discover", (service: Service) => {}); // nope
```

This works. Now I have a second class which is expecting an implementation of `Emitter<any>`:

```
class Watcher<E extends Emitter<any>> {
  constructor(emitter: E) {}
}
```

And I have an implementation of an `Emitter<Api>` for which I used `implements` like so

```
class ObjectManager implements Emitter<Api> {
  public async on<E extends keyof Api>(
    event: E,
    listener: Api[E]
  ): Promise<void> {
    // implementation omitted for the sake of this example
  }

  public async off<E extends keyof Api>(
    event: E,
    listener: Api[E]
  ): Promise<void> {
    // implementation omitted for the sake of this example
  }
}
```

Now when I try to pass in instance of the `ObjectManager` to the `Watcher` class I get a type error:

```
const watcher = new Watcher(this.objectManager);
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

> ```
> Argument of type 'ObjectManager' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Emitter<any>'.
>   Types of property 'on' are incompatible.
>     Type '<E extends "discover" | "service">(event: E, listener: Api[E]) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to type '<E extends string | number | symbol>(event: E, listener: any) => any'.
>       Types of parameters 'event' and 'event' are incompatible.
>         Type 'E' is not assignable to type '"discover" | "service"'.
>           Type 'string | number | symbol' is not assignable to type '"discover" | "service"'.
>             Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"discover" | "service"'.
>               Type 'E' is not assignable to type '"service"'.
>                 Type 'string | number | symbol' is not assignable to type '"service"'.
>                   Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"service"'.ts(2345)
> ```

I can do this however:

```
const watcher = new Watcher(this.objectManager as Emitter<Api>);
```

which works.

Now I am wondering what's wrong. Am I maybe using `implements` wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in generic `E`, It is different thing on the level of the `Emitter` and different introduced on the `ObjectManager` level. The clue is to remove one from these two generics. My proposition is to put this generic higher in `Emitter` interface

```
interface Emitter<A extends {} = {}, E extends keyof A = keyof A> {
  on: (event: E, listener: A[E]) => any;
  off: (event: E, listener: A[E]) => any;
}
// or no generic for event version:
interface Emitter<A extends {} = {}> {
  on: (event: keyof A, listener: A[typeof event]) => any;
  off: (event: keyof A, listener: A[typeof event]) => any;
}
```

Now the implementation works, as there is no generic conflicts, and generic introduced in `ObjectManager` is only one introduced on the function level:

```
// below everything works.
class ObjectManager implements Emitter<Api> {
  public async on<E extends keyof Api>(
    event: E,
    listener: Api[E]
  ): Promise<void> {
    // implementation omitted for the sake of this example
  }

  public async off<E extends keyof Api>(
    event: E,
    listener: Api[E]
  ): Promise<void> {
    // implementation omitted for the sake of this example
  }
}
const e = new Watcher(new ObjectManager());
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad, ObjectManager of course is implemented with the types according to Emitter<Api> . Using any of course would work but that would defeat the purpose

Comment: Thank you. My Watcher implementation must be wrong, this code does not work for me. I posted an example in a TS Playground. Unfortunately the link is too long so I had to copy the link in a Gist (omg) https://gist.github.com/LukasBombach/916ed5aca4532eef0a41d0266d74a314